# Why is my Rails app receiving requests with jQuery code in the URL?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, url, httpwebrequest, heroku

Our production Rails 2.3.5 app, running on Heroku, is receiving bizarre requests that include snippets of JavaScript in the URL. We have error reporting set up with Hoptoad/Airbrake on Heroku, where I'm seeing requests like the following:

> http://cooksnetwork.williams-sonoma.com/publishers/448/widgets/;if(c.css(this[a],
>   http://cooksnetwork.williams-sonoma.com/publishers/448/widgets/);f=e.css(
>   http://cooksnetwork.williams-sonoma.com/publishers/448/widgets/,c.css(this[a],
>   http://cooksnetwork.williams-sonoma.com/publishers/448/widgets/).css(

These are RESTful routes, with widgets nested under publishers. The strings following `widgets/` are found in the minified jQuery 1.4.2 source, which we have in `public/javascripts`. Each request results in an **ActionView::MissingTemplate** error, with everything between `widgets/` and `.css` being interpreted as the desired action, ex.:

> ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template widgets/;if(c.erb in view path app/views

It seems to be the same four snippets, in the same order, occurring as a set every 1-5 minutes and taking 1-2 minutes from start to finish. The publisher ID varies over time.

These errors have been logged over 60,000 times now. Does anyone have similar experience or an idea what's happening?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a polling function somewhere that broke?  You also might want to check recent code changes for any change that could have created a recursive loop to cause those 60,000 hits.

Comment: The timing isn't consistent, and our only periodic task is hourly. The 60,000 hits occurred over about 3 weeks (which I should have mentioned).

Answer (score 0):

Is this site public? Someone might be trying to find XSS exploits

Comment: The site is public, but I don't see how these snippets of jQuery would expose vulnerabilities; they aren't even complete operations, and I don't imagine many Rails apps accept URL parameters as executable JavaScript. But I'm stumped, so who knows... =)